# Should I overwrite the initial commit in github ?

Tags: git, github

I have made my first commit in github last year and I want to commit another one. Should I replace that first commit or add a new commit. How to do it ?

Comment: Wrong approach and terminology. Confusion about how `git` works. Take an hour to read [documentation of `git`](https://git-scm.com/docs) and look at the short videos there.

Comment: Don't have the time @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Then don't use github. The videos there are really excellent. In 20 minutes you'll be able to understand the basics of `git`. If you don't even have them, stop using github. As you ask it, your question does not have any sense. And if you don't take time to learn how to use any version control system, you'll later lose days or weeks of work. You can't do software development without version control today. In practice, you should do several commits per hour (not once every few months).

Comment: @Inertia, if you "don't have the time" to read some basic documentation why should we make the time to help you? You're [expected to put in at least as much effort as we do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/354577). This isn't a place for us to do your work for you; it's a place where you can _learn_.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a beginner, keep the history as it is and add a new commit. This is the normal way to use git.

And (really) take some time to read some basic tutorials on git

Answer (score -1):

Most people keep the first commit in GitHub. It's no big deal to change it, just a bit strange.

The idea is the same as with any commit: override and push force.

```
git commit --amend (change message in the editor or whatever)
git push --force (will override GitHub history)
```

Comment: I believe the OP don't even understand the basics of git. He probably need to use `git commit` and `git push` (without anything more) at first